# Deallocating binary-tree structure in C

Tags: c, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I have a linked list, I guess a tree looks like this:
 [image]

```
-> grandma
    -> dad
        -> me
        -> sister
            -> niece
        -> brother
    -> uncle
        -> cousin
```

and I have a struct as following

```
struct Node{
    Node *parent;
    Node *next;
    Node *child;
}
```

How would I free that linked list?
My idea is to do a depth first search and deallocate each node?

Comment: I don't need additonal array with pointers

Comment: @andre, btw, the illustration of family tree is nice. :)

Comment: @andre well i haven't voted down but if I may guess it is because you haven't tried a solution yourself and are just asking for one.

Comment: Usually you tick an answer when your problem is solved and the answer has provided a solution. I cannot understand why did you change your ticks 3 times already, @andre.

Comment: @MateuszKwasniak I have a problem with the iterative solution and the recursive one. when I give the root to the function, the number of deleted nodes are 2747, however the number of created nodes are 5520. Do those functions remove all the nodes and the childeren too?

Comment: I'd ask another question, posting your implementation there and linking this question. I have to take a look at your code to say what's wrong, @andre.

Comment: @MateuszKwasniak I made another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32741705/free-a-binary-tree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Recursive depth-search (DFS)**: You're right, it's a good way to dealocate binary-tree memory:

```
remove(node):
    if node is null: return

    //else
    remove(left node)
    remove(right node)

    free(node)
```

**Iterative solution**:
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/478/free-a-binary-tree
Since you don't want to use any recursive solution, there you can find well-described *iterative* one.

Comment: I don't want a recursive solution, can you provide an iterative one ?

Comment: @andre it will always be sort of a recursive solution (since it is a recursive data structure). Can be explicit or implicit by simulating a stack with an array.

Comment: @Henry I need a pseudo code of the iterative solution please

Comment: @MateuszKwasniak what is left and right in my structure is it child and next ? what about parent node ?

Comment: We do not know now how you implementation works. In binary tree, each node has left and right child (and a parent). Look at some binary trees and answer yourself, @andre.

Comment: @andre, you don't need the parent node to free the whole tree.

Answer (score 2):

You can optimize allocation/deallocation of the tree.

Imagine, you want to create tree with 20 or 30 persons. You can allocate an array of 30 `Node` structs:

```
size_t currentArraySize = 30;
Node* nodes = (Node*)malloc(currentArraySize * sizeof(Node));
size_t nextFreeIndex = 0;
```

To add new element you can write simple function:

```
Node* allocateNode()
{
    // Oops! There's not more memory in the buffer.
    // Lets increase its size.
    if (nextFreeIndex >= currentArraySize) {
        currentArraySize *= 2;
        Node* newNodes = (Node*)realloc(nodes, currentArraySize * sizeof(Node));

        // Should correct pointers (thanks to user3386109)
        if (newNodes != nodes) {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < nextFreeIndex; i++) {
                if (newNodes[i]->parent != NULL)
                    newNodes[i]->parent -= nodes += newNodes;
                if (newNodes[i]->next != NULL)
                    newNodes[i]->next -= nodes += newNodes;
                if (newNodes[i]->child != NULL)
                    newNodes[i]->child -= nodes += newNodes;
            }
        }
    }

    return nodes[nextFreeIndex++];
}
```

To deallocate all nodes you can just `free` the single pointer `nodes`.

Now the code looks a little scary as wrote user3386109, so we may simplify it a little:

```
Node* allocateNode()
{
    // Oops! There's not more memory in the buffer.
    // Lets increase its size.
    if (nextFreeIndex >= currentArraySize) {
        currentArraySize *= 2;
        Node* newNodes = (Node*)realloc(nodes, currentArraySize * sizeof(Node));

        // Should correct pointers (thanks to user3386109)
        if (newNodes != nodes)
            correctPointers(newNodes, nodes);
    }

    return nodes[nextFreeIndex++];
}

#define correctPointer(pointer, oldOffset, newOffset) if (pointer != NULL) { \\
                                                          pointer -= oldOffset; \\
                                                          pointer += newOffset; \\
                                                      }

void correctPointers(Node* newNodes, Node* nodes)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nextFreeIndex; i++) {
        correntPointer(newNodes[i]->parent, nodes, newNodes);
        correntPointer(newNodes[i]->child, nodes, newNodes);
        correntPointer(newNodes[i]->next, nodes, newNodes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Binary trees in arrays are always handsome.

Comment: @MateuszKwasniak And effective in this case. :)

Comment: Not actually going to work, because `realloc` may move the entire array to a new location in memory, invalidating all of the `next`, `child`, and `parent` pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Iterative version, inspired by Day–Stout–Warren algorithm:

```
void removetree(Node *node)
{
    while(node != NULL)
    {
        Node *temp = node;

        if(node->child != NULL)
        {
            node = node->child;
            temp->child = node->next;
            node->next = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            node = node->next;
            remove(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

This algorithm somewhat like tries to convert the tree into a list single-linked with `next` pointers, which is very simple to destroy just by iterative unlinking and destroying the first item. However it never completes the conversion, because it unlinks and removes the head node as soon as it can, despite the rest of tree not being converted yet. So to say, it interleaves a *relink* step with *unlink-and-destroy* step.

We test with the `if` instruction whether the first (head) node has any children. If so, we make its child a new head and the current node becomes the new head's `next` node. This way we have one more `next` link in the first-level list. What was 'next' to the now-head node becomes a child to a previous-head node, which is now the head's first `next`.

[image: transformation step]

On the other hand if the head node has no children, it may be removed and its `next` becomes a new head.

These two steps are iterated by the `while` loop until all children are converted into siblings and removed afterwards.

Answer (score -3):

You may use recursive solution

```
free(root)
{
    if (root->next == null)
    {
        free(node)
    }
    free(root->left)
    free(right->)
}
```

Comment: 1. He doesn't want a recursive one. 2. Your code is completely bad atm.