# Free a binary tree without recursion

Tags: c, algorithm

refering to the question [Deallocating binary-tree structure in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32733353/deallocating-binary-tree-structure-in-c?noredirect=1#comment53322817_32733353)

```
struct Node{
    Node *parent;
    Node *next;
    Node *child;
}
```

I tried to free a binary tree. The problem I have is the allocated objects are 5520 and the number of calls to the free functions is 2747. I don't know why, it should really free and iterate all over the nodes in the tree, here is the code that I use

```
int number_of_iterations =0;
int number_of_deletions =0;
    void removetree(Node *node)
    {
        number_of_iterations++;
        while(node != NULL)
        {
            Node *temp = node;

            if(node->child != NULL)
            {
                node = node->child;
                temp->child = node->next;
                node->next = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                node = node->next;
                remove(temp);
                number_of_deletions++ 
            }
        }
    }
```

Number of iteration is 5440 and the number of deletions is 2747.

New Fixed code: is that code correct ?

```
 const Node *next(const Node *node)
    {
        if (node == NULL) return NULL;
        if (node->child) return node->child;

        while (node && node->next == NULL) {
            node = node->parent;
        }

        if (node) return node->next;
        return NULL;
    }

 for ( p= ctx->obj_root; p; p = next(p)) {
      free(p);
     }
```

Comment: Please post the definition of `Node` structure. Your code is currently incomplete and can't be clearly interpreted.

Comment: @Transcendental I have added it

Comment: test this code for much smaller number of nodes - like 1, 2, 3 - probably that will be enough to see the reason...

Comment: Is this really a binary tree? It rather looks like a chained linked list or something home-brewed. Binary trees have a `right` and a `left` member.

Comment: Ok judging by the link, it is not a binary tree but a "family tree". Okay...

Comment: you usually free trees which recursion, not loops

Comment: it doesn't free the parent nodes, it just goes deeply and removes the nodes, leaving the parents

Comment: @DavidHaim The advantage of having a parent member is that you can get rid of the slow, dangerous, stack-slaughtering, unreadable recursion. At the expense of data memory consumption.

Comment: @weston yes it has a child and a next

Comment: @Lundin the names might be odd, but this is a binary tree. `next` and `child` are just odd names for `left` and `right`..

Comment: @Lundin Can you provide an iterative solution ?

Comment: Your code doesn't look anything like the link you posted to. In particular this one: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/489/15982

Comment: Non-recursive traversal of a tree (for whatever purpose) is only possible through use of `parent` pointers. This is the very reason your data structure includes these pointers. Yet your code never uses `parent` pointers, which immediately means that it is incorrect.

Comment: Actually, the purpose of the data structure you have there (a tree with a list of child nodes) is to represent *any* tree, not necessarily a *binary* tree. Your tree is not actually "binary". (It is true that *any* tree can be represented by an equivalent *binary* tree, meaning that if you want you can see it as "binary", but this is completely besides the point.) The question you linked at the beginning does not work with binary trees either - a parent can have more than two children, as is the case in your example there. So, it is not clear why you insist on calling it "binary".

Comment: I updated the code which uses the parent pointer, Is that code correct ?

Comment: @AnT "Your tree is not actually "binary"" Why?, it has two other identical nodes, a left and right, here called child and next.

Comment: You don't need parent, did you look at the link: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/478/free-a-binary-tree/489#489

Comment: @weston: As I said, *any* tree can be *interpreted* as a *binary* tree. There's 1:1 correspondence between arbitrary trees and binary trees. The "child list" representation used above illustrates that fact very clearly. The distinction between "binary" and "non-binary" trees is completely inconsequential and is a matter of pure convenience. And it has nothing to do the task at hand. That's the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: @AnT Have to agree to disagree maybe. They may call it child, but it's just another *tree node*, it is **not** a child list. There is no "child list" representation here, just a poor choice of field names.

Comment: @weston: No, no, no. The above representation is a *canonical* and extremely widely used representation of an *arbitrary* (non-binary) tree. Each node stores a pointer to its first child and its next sibling. The field names are canonical as well. It is true that the representation is physically equivalent to a binary tree (with "poorly chosen filed names"), but the people who wrote that code did not want to see it in terms of binary trees. The found it more convenient (more readable) to see it in terms of arbitrary trees. This is their conscious choice. There's nothing "poor" here.

Comment: @AnT I get it (finally!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your nodes do indeed contain valid `parent` pointers, then the whole thing can be done in a much more compact and readable fashion

```
void removetree(Node *node)
{
  while (node != NULL)
  {
    Node *next = node->child;

    /* If child subtree exists, we have to delete that child subtree 
       first. Once the child subtree is gone, we'll be able to delete 
       this node. At this moment, if child subtree exists, don't delete
       anything yet - just descend into the child subtree */

    node->child = NULL;
    /* Setting child pointer to null at this early stage ensures that 
       when we emerge from child subtree back to this node again, we will 
       be aware of the fact that child subtree is gone */

    if (next == NULL)
    { /* Child subtree does not exist - delete the current node, 
         and proceed to sibling node. If no sibling, the current 
         subtree is fully deleted - ascend to parent */
      next = node->next != NULL ? node->next : node->parent;
      remove(node); // or `free(node)`
    }

    node = next;
  }
}
```

Comment: @andre: I'm not sure what you want explained. The code implements the classic non-recursive traversal strategy: go to child, go to sibling, go to parent (choose the first one available). All that one needs to do is to add your `remove` (or `free`) call in the appropriate spot.

Comment: Suppose I have one root node and one child and 3 sibilings. Then I supply the root node for removeTree. First it goes to the one child, but next is not null at this case so it won't go to the next node and remove it. I'm willing to learn and I want to understand how it works.

Comment: @AnT, I'm afraid you are not correct.  To traverse a tree (a recursively, non linear defined) structure, you need some way to store the pointers you are breaking on freeing.  If you don't you'll get up to the same point as the op.  Iterative aproaches involve a linked list, some kind of buffering to store all the unlinked nodes that you get from traversing the tree...  but you have used nothing... How did you do it?  (And no explanation at all!!!!)

Comment: @Luis Colorado: Yes, I'm correct. A tree would indeed constitute "a recursive structure", if it did not have `parent` pointers. Once you add `parent` pointers to a tree, it is no longer a recursive structure. It becomes a graph that can be easily traversed by a purely iterative algorithm. The algorithm is so basic that an explanation can be found rather easily on the net. This is essentially the "follow the left wall" algorithm for traversing a labyrinth. As you probably know, a non-cyclic labyrinth can be explored exhaustively by following its left wall.

Comment: The same thing is done by the non-recursive tree traversal algorithm I refer to. But in order to use that algorithm you need means to get from any tree node to any adjacent tree node. This is when `parent` pointers come into play. In order to use this algorithm for tree destruction (as above), all you need to to do is to make sure you don't deallocate anything prematurely. I.e. deallocated lower-level nodes before higher-level nodes. This is what I do above.

Comment: In any case, what you see above is basically 4 lines of code. Is that so difficult to figure out what they do? I thought them self-explanatory. If you believe it is incorrect, you surely should be able to come up with a counterexample.

Comment: @AnT it's correct and I have already used it in my code. but why you do this line  node->child = NULL;? what is the point of it ?

Comment: @andre: The algorithm first attempts to go to the child, then (if no child) it attempts to go to the sibling and then (if no sibling) it goes to the parent. Now, once we returned to the parent (from child) we need to make sure that we don't try to go to the child again, i.e. we don't cycle forever. This is why we do: `->child = NULL`. We basically "burn that bridge" to make sure we never attempt to walk over it again. The fact that the `child` pointer is now null is what forces us to proceed to the sibling once we return to that node.

Comment: Moreover, by the time we return from child to parent, the child is already destroyed (deallocated). I.e. the `->child` pointer is no longer valid. It makes sense to set it to null to indicate the fact that the child subtree no longer exists.

Comment: you mean from a sibling to parent ? how do you return from a child to parent ?

Comment: @andre: Well, one the one hand you are right - "from sibling to parent". On the other hand, all siblings are conceptually "children" of the same parent. I.e. you do return from child to parent. All `parent` links lead "from child to parent".

Comment: @AnT, I agree with you, but such a tree (with a parent link, something that uses more memory) can be traversed, but not deleting nodes as you traverse, because when you follow one path and deleting the traversed nodes you delete *the other path access* so you will end in the same situation as the OP.  You have to remember the open, unvisited paths so you can return there when you reach a dead end.  The only way to have such a graph and delete nodes without breaking the tree is to make a n-passes algorithm that only deletes leaf nodes and nodes with only one child (adjusting the links)

Comment: ... or you can make a two pass traverse (first filling a list with the pointers to the already traversed nodes) and a second pass to delete the nodes.  This is equivalent *to add parent links to all the nodes* indeed, but you only need it to make the deletion.

Comment: @Luis Colorado: I don't know where you got the idea that I "follow one path and delete the traversed nodes". I *don't* delete the nodes as I follow the path *down* from root to children. The nodes are deleted *only* on the way *up*, when the subtree is already gone (which is exactly what's ensured by the `if` in the above code). The tree above the current node is always kept intact, and this is exactly why I can always return through `parent` links "when I reach dead end".

Comment: Your assertion that this is only possible by "doing n passes and deleting only leaf nodes" makes no sense whatsoever. Such assertion would make sense if we had no `parent` links in the tree, as I stated many times before. But we do have them. Anyway, the bottom line here is that the code above is perfectly correct and correctly deletes the tree. Your unsupported claims that "it can't work because it can't work"... well, sorry, they just make no sense to me. Surely, if you see a clear problem in this implementation, you should be able to build a counterexample. Do you have a counterexample?

Comment: @AnT, I have published an iterative solution that doesn't require the `parent` pointer.   Requiring a `parent` pointer is a costly option in case you are going to manage actually big trees.

Comment: @Luis Colorado: That's great, but firstly, we have a specific statement of a problem from the OP, which *does* include `parent` pointers. My answer is made in that context. Secondly, there's always a trade-off between pros and cons of `parent` pointers. For one example, the possibility to implement a tree iterator of *constant* size is a huge benefit provided by `parent` pointers. Whether the OP can (and wants to) afford the cost of `parent` pointers is for the OP to decide.

Comment: @Luis Colorado: Your solution is indeed iterative, but completely infeasible in practice: doing repretitive rescans of the entire remaining tree starting from the root each time is prohibitively expensive. That is why we add "excessive" `parent` pointers to tree nodes sometimes: to pay a small price in terms of memory to obtain a *massive* gain in performance (as compared to your implementation).

Comment: @AnT, totally in agreement with you. I'm not trying to give a good solution. I'm trying to illustrate a solution with **no extra memory** and **pure iterative** (so no queues are used, and no dynamic memory used to buffer the pointers and orphan nodes we are collecting in the erasure process).  I'm trying to illustrate the problems you get into when you try to solve a recursive problem in a non recursive way.  Did you read about the Physics exam of Neils Bohr and Sir Ernst Rutherford?

Comment: ... and now, memory is cheap, you can use parent pointers as you like, queues or stacks to overcome recursive definitions.

Comment: The basic problem here is that you **actually** need some dynamic allocation structure to get rid of the undeleted nodes that you get.  For each fully populated node (not a leaf node) that you erase, you get **two** unreferenced nodes, so the number of nodes to be recorded grows exponentially (you need a dynamic memory structure to store them, or the algorithm I put in the solution)

Comment: By the way, your solution **is incorrect**, as it doesn't process both children in a complete node, so it leads forcefully to a memory leak.  You don't present a complete (testable) example and mine has been tested (you have only to execute it to see that it erases all nodes)

Comment: @Luis Colorado: Again, you are confused about how my solution works. Your assertion about "number of nodes to be recorded grows exponentially" is only true is the nodes are erased in "top-to-bottom" order. Only in this case you will two child nodes to memorize each time you erase a parent node. My solution works in "bottom-to-top" order. By the time I erase a node, its left subtree (`child` pointer) is already guaranteed to be erased. For this reason, there's always no more than one node to "memorize".  And this is exactly why it is possible to build a purely iterative solution.

Comment: Your assertion that my solution is "incorrect" is ridiculous. Yes, my solution does erase all nodes. And no, it does not lead to any memory leaks. Meanwhile, your complaint about "testable examples" is ridiculous as well. "Examples" cannot be used to prove the correctness of a solution, regardless of how many one provides. However, examples can be used to prove that a solution is wrong. Just one counterexample is enough for that. You claim that my solution is incorrect. If so, you should be able to build a counterexample. Can you do it?

Answer (score 3):

This **is** a binary tree! It's confusing people because of the names you have chosen, `next` is common in a linked list but the types are what matters and you have one node referencing exactly two identical nodes types and that's all that matters.

Taken from here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/489/15982 which you linked to. And I renamed `left` to `child` and `right` to `next` :)

```
void removetree(Node *root) {
    struct Node * node = root;
    struct Node * up = NULL;

    while (node != NULL) {
        if (node->child != NULL) {
            struct Node * child = node->child;
            node->child = up;
            up = node;
            node = child;
        } else if (node->next != NULL) {
            struct Node * next = node->next;
            node->child = up;
            node->next = NULL;
            up = node;
            node = next;
        } else {
            if (up == NULL) {
                free(node);
                node = NULL;
            }
            while (up != NULL) {
                free(node);
                if (up->next != NULL) {
                    node = up->next;
                    up->next = NULL;
                    break;
                } else {
                    node = up;
                    up = up->child;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you do need `parent` pointer. In this case you simply hijack `left` pointer in order to use it as a `parent` pointer. The only reason you can do that is that the tree is being destructed, allowing us to easily hijack and re-purpose node fields. However, if the original data structure already has readily available `parent` pointers, the same thing can be done in much more compact and readable fashion.

Comment: Upvote for the comment that arbitrary trees can be modelled as binary trees.

Comment: @AnT instead of thinking of it as hijacked, think of it as restructuring the tree during it's destruction.

Comment: @AnT I'd like to reiterate that this is code from that question the OP linked to that they were having trouble implementing. I agree it's not easy to follow.

Comment: @weston Yes indeed, but it is an often overlooked fact.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old post, but i hope my answer helps someone in the future.
Here is my implementation of BinaryTree and it's operations in c++ without recursion, the logics can be easily implemented in C.

Each node owns a pointer to the parent node to make things easier.

NOTE: the inorderPrint() function used for printing out the tree's content uses recursion.

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
class BinaryTree
{
    
    struct node
    {
        //the binary tree node consists of a parent node for making things easier as you'll see below
        node(T t)
        {
            value = t;
            
        }
        ~node() {  }
        struct node *parent = nullptr;
        T value;
        struct node *left   = nullptr;
        struct node *right  = nullptr;
    };
    node* _root;

    //gets inorder predecessor
    node getMinimum(node* start)
    {
        
        while(start->left)
        {
            start = start->left;
        }
        return *start;
    }
    /*
        this is the only code that uses recursion
        to print the inorder traversal of the binary tree
    */
    void inorderTraversal(node* rootNode)
    {
        
        if (rootNode)
        {
            
            inorderTraversal(rootNode->left);
            std::cout << rootNode->value<<" ";
            inorderTraversal(rootNode->right);
            
        }
        
    }
    int count;
public:
    int Count()
    {
        return count;
    }
    void Insert(T val)
    {
        count++;
        node* tempRoot = _root;
    
        if (_root == nullptr)
        {
            
            _root = new node(val);
            _root->parent = nullptr;
            
        }
        else
        {
            while (tempRoot)
            {

                if (tempRoot->value < val)
                {
                    if (tempRoot->right)
                        tempRoot = tempRoot->right;
                    else
                    {
                        tempRoot->right = new node(val );
                        tempRoot->right->parent = tempRoot;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if (tempRoot->value > val)
                {
                    if (tempRoot->left)
                        tempRoot = tempRoot->left;
                    else
                    {
                        tempRoot->left = new node(val);
                        tempRoot->left->parent = tempRoot;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout<<"value already exists";
                    count--;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    void inorderPrint()
    {
        inorderTraversal(_root);
        std::cout <<std::endl;
    }
    void Delete(T val)
    {
        node *tempRoot = _root;
        //find the node with the value first
        while (tempRoot!= nullptr)
        {
            if (tempRoot->value == val)
            {
                break;
            }
            
            if (tempRoot->value > val)
            {
                tempRoot = tempRoot->left;
            }
            else
            {
                tempRoot = tempRoot->right;
            }
            
            
        }
        //if such node is found then delete that node
        if (tempRoot)
        {
            //if it contains both left and right child replace the current node's value with inorder predecessor
            if (tempRoot->right && tempRoot->left)
            {
                node inordPred = getMinimum(tempRoot->right);
                Delete(inordPred.value);
                count++;
                tempRoot->value = inordPred.value;
                
            }
            else if (tempRoot->right)
            {
                /*if it only contains right child, then get the current node's parent
                * check if the current node is the parent's left child or right child
                * replace the respective pointer of the parent with the right child of the current node
                * 
                * finally change the child's parent to the new parent
                */
                if (tempRoot->parent)
                {
                    if (tempRoot->parent->right == tempRoot)
                    {
                        tempRoot->parent->right = tempRoot->right;
                    }
                    if (tempRoot->parent->left == tempRoot)
                    {
                        tempRoot->parent->left = tempRoot->right;
                    }
                    tempRoot->right->parent = tempRoot->parent;
                }
                else
                {
                    //if there is no parent then it's a root node
                    //root node should point to the current node's child
                    
                    
                    _root = tempRoot->right;
                    _root->parent = nullptr;
                    delete tempRoot;
                }
                
            }
            else if (tempRoot->left)
            {
                /*
                * same logic as we've done for the right node
                */
                if (tempRoot->parent)
                {
                    if (tempRoot->parent->right == tempRoot)
                    {
                        tempRoot->parent->right = tempRoot->left;
                    }
                    if (tempRoot->parent->left == tempRoot)
                    {
                        tempRoot->parent->left = tempRoot->left;
                    }
                    tempRoot->left->parent =tempRoot->parent ;
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    
                    _root = tempRoot->left;
                    _root->parent = nullptr;
                    delete tempRoot;
                }
                
            }
            else
            {
                /*
                * if it's a leaf node, then check which ptr (left or right) of the parent is pointing to 
                * the pointer to be deleted (tempRoot)
                * then replace that pointer with a nullptr
                * then delete the (tempRoot)
                */
                if (tempRoot->parent)
                {
                    if (tempRoot->parent->right == tempRoot)
                    {
                        tempRoot->parent->right = nullptr;
                    }
                    else if (tempRoot->parent->left == tempRoot)
                    {
                        tempRoot->parent->left = nullptr;
                    }
                    delete tempRoot;
                }
                else
                {
                    //if the leaf node is a root node ,then delete it and set it to null
                    delete _root;
                    _root = nullptr;
                }
                
            }
            count--;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "No element found";
        }
    }
    
    void freeTree()
    {
        //the output it produces will be that of a preorder traversal
        std::cout << "freeing tree:";
        node* end=_root;
        node* parent=nullptr;
        while (end)
        {
            //go to the node with least value
            if (end->left)
                end = end->left;
            else if (end->right)
            {
                //if it's already at the least value, then check if it has a right sub tree
                //if it does then set it as "end" ptr so that the loop will check for the least node in this subtree
                end = end->right;
            }
            else
            {
                //if it's a leaf node then it should be deleted and it's parent's (left or right pointer )
                //should be safely set to nullptr
                //then end should be set to the parent pointer
                //so that it we can repeat the process for all other nodes that's left
                std::cout << end->value<<" ";
                parent = end->parent;
                if (parent)
                {
                    if (parent->left == end)
                        parent->left = nullptr;
                    else
                        parent->right = nullptr;
                    delete end;
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    delete end;
                    _root = nullptr;
                }
                
                count--;
                end = parent;
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    ~BinaryTree()
    {
        freeTree();
    }
};


int main()
{
    BinaryTree<int> bt;
    bt.Insert(3);
    bt.Insert(2);
    bt.Insert(1);
    bt.Insert(5);
    bt.Insert(4);
    bt.Insert(6);
    std::cout << "before deletion:\n";
    bt.inorderPrint();
    bt.Delete(5);
    bt.Delete(2);
    bt.Delete(1);
    bt.Delete(4);
    std::cout << "after deletion:\n";
    bt.inorderPrint();
    bt.freeTree();
    std::cout << "\nCount: " << bt.Count()<<"\n";
}
```

output:

```
before deletion:
1 2 3 4 5 6
after deletion:
3 6
freeing tree:6 3
Count: 0
freeing tree:
```

Answer (score 1):

First to say is that if you try to solve a recursive problem in a non-recursive way, you'll run into trouble.

I have seen a wrong answer selected as the good one, so I'll try to show my approach:

I'll begin using pointer references instead of plain pointers, as passing a root pointer reference makes it easier to detect (and update) the pointers to the root node.  So the interface to the routine will be:

```
void delete_tree(struct node * * const ref);
```

It represents a reference to the pointer that points to the root node.  I'll descend to the node and, if one of `child` or `next` is `NULL` then this node can be freely eliminated by just making the referenced pointer to point to the other link (so I'll not lose it).  If the node has two children (`child` and `next` are both `!= NULL`) then I cannot delete this node until one of the branches has collapsed, and then I select one of the branches and move the reference (I declared the `ref` parameter `const` to assure I don't modify it, so I use another *moving* reference for this)

```
struct node **moving_reference;
```

Then, the algorithm follows:

```
void tree_delete(struct node ** const static_ref)
{
    while (*static_ref) {
        struct node **moving_ref = static_ref;

        while (*moving_ref) {
            struct node *to_be_deleted = NULL;

            if ((*moving_ref)->child && (*moving_ref)->next) {
                /* we have both children, we cannot delete until
                 * ulterior pass. Just move the reference. */
                moving_ref = &(*moving_ref)->child;
            } else if ((*moving_ref)->child) {
                /* not both != NULL and child != NULL, 
                 * so next == NULL */
                to_be_deleted = *moving_ref;
                *moving_ref = to_be_deleted->child;
            } else {
                /* not both != NULL and child == NULL,
                 * so follow next */
                to_be_deleted = *moving_ref;
                *moving_ref = to_be_deleted->next;
            } /* if, else if */
            /* now, delete the unlinked node, if available */
            if (to_be_deleted) node_delete(to_be_deleted);
        } /* while (*moving_ref) */
    } /* while (*static_ref) */
} /* delete_tree */
```

I have included this algorithm in a complete example, showing you the partial trees and the position of `moving_ref` as it moves through the tree.  It also shows the passes needed to delete it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 100

#define D(x) __FILE__":%d:%s: " x, __LINE__, __func__

#define ASSERT(x) do { \
        int res; \
        printf(D("ASSERT: (" #x ") ==> %s\n"), \
                        (res = (int)(x)) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"); \
        if (!res) exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
} while (0)

struct node {
        int key;
        struct node *child;
        struct node *next;
}; /* struct node */

struct node *node_alloc(void);
void node_delete(struct node *n);

/* This routine has been written recursively to show the simplicity
 * of traversing the tree when you can use recursive algorithms. */
void tree_traverse(struct node *n, struct node *p, int lvl)
{
    while(n) {
        printf(D("%*s[%d]\n"), lvl<<2, p && p == n ? ">" : "", n->key);
        tree_traverse(n->child, p, lvl+1);
        n = n->next;
    } /* while */
} /* tree_traverse */

void tree_delete(struct node ** const static_ref)
{
    int pass;

    printf(D("BEGIN\n"));

    for (pass = 1; *static_ref; pass++) {
        struct node **moving_ref = static_ref;

        printf(D("Pass #%d: Considering node %d:\n"),
                        pass, (*moving_ref)->key);

        while (*moving_ref) {
            struct node *to_be_deleted = NULL;

            /* print the tree before deciding what to do. */
            tree_traverse(*static_ref, *moving_ref, 0);

            if ((*moving_ref)->child && (*moving_ref)->next) {
                printf(D("Cannot remove, Node [%d] has both children, "
                                        "skip to 'child'\n"),
                                (*moving_ref)->key);
                /* we have both children, we cannot delete until
                 * ulterior pass. Just move the reference. */
                moving_ref = &(*moving_ref)->child;
            } else if ((*moving_ref)->child) {
                /* not both != NULL and child != NULL, 
                 * so next == NULL */
                to_be_deleted = *moving_ref;
                printf(D("Deleting [%d], link through 'child' pointer\n"),
                                to_be_deleted->key);
                *moving_ref = to_be_deleted->child;
            } else {
                /* not both != NULL and child != NULL,
                 * so follow next */
                to_be_deleted = *moving_ref;
                printf(D("Deleting [%d], link through 'next' pointer\n"),
                                to_be_deleted->key);
                *moving_ref = to_be_deleted->next;
            } /* if, else if */

            /* now, delete the unlinked node, if available */
            if (to_be_deleted) node_delete(to_be_deleted);
        } /* while (*moving_ref) */
        printf(D("Pass #%d end.\n"), pass);
    } /* for */

    printf(D("END.\n"));
} /* delete_tree */

struct node heap[N] = {0};
size_t allocated = 0;
size_t deleted = 0;

/* simple allocation/free routines, normally use malloc(3). */
struct node *node_alloc()
{
        return heap + allocated++;
} /* node_alloc */

void node_delete(struct node *n)
{
        if (n->key == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr,
                                D("doubly freed node %ld\n"),
                                (n - heap));
        }
        n->key = -1;
        n->child = n->next = NULL;
        deleted++;
} /* node_delete */

/* main simulation program. */
int main()
{
        size_t i;

        printf(D("Allocating %d nodes...\n"), N);
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                struct node *n;

                n = node_alloc(); /* the node */
                n->key = i;
                n->next = NULL;
                n->child = NULL;

                printf(D("Node %d"), n->key);

                if (i) { /* when we have more than one node */
                        /* get a parent for it. */
                        struct node *p = heap + (rand() % i);

                        printf(", parent %d", p->key);
                        /* insert as a child of the parent */
                        n->next = p->child;
                        p->child = n;
                } /* if */
                printf("\n");
        } /* for */

        struct node *root = heap;

        ASSERT(allocated == N);
        ASSERT(deleted == 0);

        printf(D("Complete tree:\n"));
        tree_traverse(root, NULL, 0);

        tree_delete(&root);

        ASSERT(allocated == N);
        ASSERT(deleted == N);
} /* main */
```

Comment: So, you first stated that having `parent` references is too expensive in large trees, but then you came up with a solution that performs repetitive rescans of the entire tree again, again and again (!), deleting only "degree 2" nodes on each rescan. While it saves memory by omitting `parent` pointers, the price you pay for that in terms of execution time is enormous. It is catastrophically expensive. An implementation like that can only have illustrational value, but no practical value at all.

Comment: Well, look at my first paragraph that says trying to solve a recursive problem in a non recursive way...   By the way, my solution tries to save memory, not allocating a buffer of already traversed nodes, to get more pointers for children.  What is true is that as long as you traverse the tree, you get more and more references to nodes to traverse and you have to store them in some way.  The no-store algorithm is something like this.  Of course, this algorithm is not recommendable, but also isn't to solve the problem in a non recursive way.  The OP does not say anything about that.

Comment: As I tell you in another comment, for each complete node (two children) you have two nodes to store somewhere once you erase the one you are in.  Of course you can make one of the children the actual child of the erased parent, but you have to cope with the other.  Either case, you can avoid the descend from the root using the parent, but the algorithm doesn't change... you have to iterate through three pointers into a labirinth searching for leave nodes (or only one child) to erase.  You'll get a lot of navigations and unlink/link operations before you fully erase the tree.

Comment: Above you claim that "you have two nodes to store somewhere once you erase the one you are in", which is only true if you insist on erasing parent before the children. At the same time in your own algorithm you are erasing children first. So, what is the importance of the "two nodes to store" if you already realize that other deletion orders are possible? There's no requirement to erase parents before children. My solution always erases left subtree before erasing the parent. So, by the time we get to erasing the parent, only one node has to be stored.

Comment: This is exactly what permits a purely iterative implementation without any rescanning of the full tree. All you need is a non-recursive traversal algorithm. And when the tree has `parent` links, non-recursive traversal is easy.

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
void removeTree(Node *node){
    Node *temp;
    while (node !=NULL){
        if (node->child != NULL) {
            removeTree(node->child);
        }
        temp = node;
        node = node->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

Non-recursive version:

```
void removeTree(Node *node){
    Node *temp;
    while (node !=NULL){
        temp = node;
        while(temp != node) {
            for(;temp->child == NULL; temp = temp->child); //Go to the leaf
            if (temp->next == NULL)
                free(temp); //free the leaf
            else { // If there is a next move it to the child an repeat
                temp->child = temp->next;
                temp->next = temp->next->next;
            }
        }
        node = temp->next; // Move to the next
        free(temp)
    }
}
```

I think this should work

Comment: I don't want it recursively, I'm running it on an embedded system.

Comment: Added a non-recursive method, hope it works. But you definitely must edit your post to reflect you wanted a non-recursive way

Comment: You don't remove the parent object in your code, and you are not using the parent pointer, is it necessary to use it ?

Comment: What? I'm freeing the parent in free(temp). 

You mustn't free every pointer you use, just the memory it's pointing to. So, if p->child = q and q->parent = p, you should never do free(q->parent) and free(p) cause you would be freeing two times the same memory direction (Same with free(q) and free(p->child))

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this recurisively?

```
void removetree(Node *node) {
  if (node == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  number_of_iterations++;
  removetree(node->next);
  removetree(node->child);
  free(node);
  number_of_deletions++;
}
```

Comment: I don't want it recursively, I'm running it on an embedded system.

Comment: Because he has a parent member, so he doesn't have to. Recursion  should always be avoided if possible.

Comment: We know they have 5520 elements, so it could be either very deep (childs) or long (nexts) and cause a stackoverflow.

Comment: @Lundin Do you have an iterative solution ?

Comment: @andre For binary trees, yes. For "family trees", no.

Comment: @Lundin In either case, the OP code seems to delete the nodes in a depth-first sequence. I don't see how the `parent` is related to this; it is not accessed in OP's code.

Comment: @Codor In a binary tree with a parent member, you would do something like: in a loop: find left-most-node, set parent in temp variable, delete node, if there is a parent->right node, make that current node, otherwise make parent current node. I might have the source code for it somewhere... Anyway, that's off topic since this is no binary tree.

Comment: @Lundin I updated the code which uses the parent pointer, Is that code correct ?

Comment: Well if there are additional constraints it would be nice to specify them in the question....

Answer (score 0):

The implementation does not work for a tree with root `1`, which has a single child `2`.

```
NodeOne.parent = null
NodeOne.next = null
NodeOne.child = NodeTwo

NodeTwo.parent = null
NodeTwo.next = null
NodeTwo.child = null
```

Execution of `Removetree(NodeOne)` will not call `remove` on `NodeOne`.

Comment: I updated the code which uses the parent pointer, Is that code correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You are freeing only  subtrees, not parent nodes. Suppose `child` represents the `left` child of the node and `next` is the `right` child. Then, your code becomes:

```
struct Node{
    Node *parent;
    Node *right;
    Node *left;
}

int number_of_iterations =0;
int number_of_deletions =0;
    void removetree(Node *node)
    {
        number_of_iterations++;
        while(node != NULL)
        {
            Node *temp = node;

            if(node->left != NULL)
            {
                node = node->left;
                temp->left = node->right;
                node->right = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                node = node->right;
                remove(temp);
                number_of_deletions++ 
            }
        }
    }
```

Each time your while loop finishes one iteration, a left sub-node will be left without a pointer to it. 
Take, for example the following tree:

```
             1
     2                3
4        5        6         7
```

When `node` is the root node, the following happens

- `node` is pointing to '1'
- `temp` is pointing to '1'
- `node` now points to  '2'
- `temp->left` now points to  '5'
- `node->right` now points to '1'

In the next iteration, you begin with 
`node` pointing to '2' and `temp` also. As you can see, you did not remove node '1'. This will repeat.

In order to fix this, you might want to consider using [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) and a queue-like structure to remove all the nodes if you want to avoid recursion.

**Edit**
BFS way:

1. Create a Queue structure `Q`
2. Add the root node `node`  to `Q`
3. Add left node of `node` to `Q`
4. Add right node of `node` to `Q`
5. Free `node` and remove it from  `Q`
6. Set `node` = first element of `Q`
7. Repeat steps 3-6 until `Q` becomes empty

This uses the fact that queue is a [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) structure.

Comment: Please can you write a pseudo code for the iterative version. I don't get the BFS apporach here.

Comment: I updated the code which uses the parent pointer, Is that code correct ?

Comment: @andre Note that you are freeing the memory and then trying to access it again  i.e. `free(p)` and then `next(p)`

Answer (score 0):

At first, I considered the code [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32741705/free-a-binary-tree-without-recursion/32745695#32745695) by [@AnT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187690/) to be incorrect, because I thought the question was about a binary tree defined in the usual way (that is, with every node referencing its left and right subtrees). With this (false!) assumption, it turns out that the node is freed immediately after its left subtree is traversed and freed, but before the same happens to the right subtree. Then, when ascending from the right subtree, we will step on the parent node, which has already been freed.

What I missed is that in the original question, the binary tree is represented as a general one, in form of a queue of unidirectional linked lists with additional inter-links to parent nodes. For clarity, I drew the following diagram, where the dashed lines indicate references to parents.

[image: https://pastebin.com/9jY4Kayh]

---

If anyone still cares, there is a correct approach for binary trees in the usual form. It still requires the parent links, though. Written in C89.

```c
void igena_avl_subtree_free( igena_avl_node_p root ) {
  igena_avl_node_p next_node;
{
  while (root != NULL) {
    if (root->left != NULL) {
      next_node = root->left;
      root->left = NULL;
    } else if (root->right != NULL) {
      next_node = root->right;
      root->right = NULL;
    } else {
      next_node = root->parent;
      free( root );
    }
    root = next_node;
  }
}}
```

Taken directly from my own project [Gena](https://github.com/cher-nov/Gena).